# textbox number type in html cut off 0 if post form in php

Tags: php, html, mobile

If i give textbox type as number and submit a form it cut off 0 .

ex: 099921 means it will post as 99921

why it cut off preceding 0

Comment: Why do you need that '0'?.If you want full number you need to declare that input type as text.

Comment: if i give input type as text it will show normal keypad in mobile ,i want to show initially numeric keypad when user hit textbox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 0 in front means nothing and is removed. Make it a string (text) and it will stay. Ints have no 0 in front.

Comment: If user want to show numeric keypad give the textbox type as tel , it will display only numbers and when we post form it didnt cut off 0  in mobile as well as browser

Answer (score 0):

```
    i dont know why but i did the same code and it is displaying the value with o i.e 099921 

check out my code
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $numberValue = $_POST['numVal'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="number" name="numVal" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: this code is worked for browser only ,In mobile it will cutoff preceding zero

Comment: It's ok, u didn't mentioned about mobile before. anyway if you want to keep 0 (zero) then change the textbox type from number to text